# Using JavaScript to pull html from external site the setting it to a string

Tags: javascript, html, web

I’m not sure if this is even possible since I can’t find anything about it but I am looking to get html off of an external site using JavaScript in my webpage using the url. So I just set a variable as a url the it can set all html on that specific webpage as a variable. I could maybe scrape the page but I don’t see anyway to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Please read about CORS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

You cannot do this directly in js unless you want to get data by API.
API sources should be available by ajax requests with JSONP format.

If you want to get external page html, you can use node.js
With library like node-curl you can do that. 
https://github.com/jiangmiao/node-curl
Than if you get page you can parse them for get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to parse html from a url. As stated before you can't do this in Javascript. If there is a site that you want to use their data you can see if they have an API which will allow you to build a web application from that data.

What you are referring to is possible using Python. It requires a library called HTML Parser.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html